# How do you add parameters to the current URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add a language modifier via query, by adding "?lang=xx" to the current URL.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
=link_to request.request_parameters.slice(:lang).merge(lang: 'en')
```

This is fine, except it adds "welcome/index" or the correspondent route when I use customized routes, which is not great for sharing links.

I also tried this:

```
=link_to "#{request.path}/?lang=en"
```

Simple, it works, but doesn't allow me to remove unwanted parameters.

I read somewhere that there was one of these that was supposed to not include "welcome/index", I've already tried `request.query_parameters` and `request.request_parameters`, both include 'welcome/index' when I do something while on my website's root.

I could add conditionals and remove the controller and action when I'm in a customized route, but I think that's unnecessary work.

Is there a clean way to do this without overengineering a solution?

I'm currently on Rails 4.2.5 and thinking on upgrading to 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

Guess I had to overengineer it. This is the simplest implementation I could think of:

Slim:

```
=link_to_if request.path == '/', 'Home', root_path(lang: :en) do
   =link_to 'Not Home', request.request_parameters.slice(:lang).merge(lang: 'en')
```

I know it's two lines, I just hate adding more code than it'd seem necessary.